# Optimizing image recognition of colored beads in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

After loads of reading and trying around i hope someone here can help me out with the final steps.

I'm about to use openCV for counting of 2 different colored objects.

[image: Input image]

I convert into an HSV image, define the boundaries for the 2 colors to get a mask with each color. Afterwards i use a kernel to smoothen the pic and correct holes.

At the end using watershed to identify the single beads in the picture. 
The algorithm doesnt work too bad but is still to unprecise especially for the blue beads, closely touching objects and the wall regions (see maskb). I'd be very tahnkful for any tipps for improvement.

The amount in the picture are ~580 blue and ~1632 white beads.

My code is the following:

```
img = cv2.imread('xxx')
#set font
font= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# shift correction
shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img, 15, 30)
#hsv conversion
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(shifted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of white color in HSV for brown background
lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 190])
upper_white = np.array([360, 255, 255])
maskw= cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)

# define range of green color in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_blue = np.array([360, 255, 48])
maskb=cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue, upper_blue)
"""MASK CORRECTION"""
# corrects open lines and holes in picture -- closing doesnt work - opening leads to better result - 5,5 is array
kernelOpen=np.ones((4,4))
kernelClose=np.ones((5,5))

#morphology mask white
maskOpenw=cv2.morphologyEx(maskw,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
maskClosew=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpenw,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

#morphology mask blue
maskOpenb=cv2.morphologyEx(maskb,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
maskCloseb=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpenb,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

""" FOR WHITE!!! - min distance factor to play"""
# compute the exact Euclidean distance from every binary
# pixel to the nearest zero pixel, then find peaks in this
# distance map
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(maskOpenw)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=9,
    labels=maskOpenw)

# perform a connected component analysis on the local peaks,
# using 8-connectivity, then appy the Watershed algorithm
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=maskOpenw)
print("[INFO] {} unique segments found".format(len(np.unique(labels)) - 1))

# loop over the unique labels returned by the Watershed
# algorithm
for label in np.unique(labels):
    # if the label is zero, we are examining the 'background'
    # so simply ignore it
    if label == 0:
        continue

    # otherwise, allocate memory for the label region and draw
    # it on the mask
    mask = np.zeros(maskOpenw.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255

    # detect contours in the mask and grab the largest one
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # draw a circle enclosing the object
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 2)
#   cv2.putText(img, "#{}".format(label), (int(x) - 10, int(y)),
#               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)

   """ FOR Blue!!!"""
# compute the exact Euclidean distance from every binary
# pixel to the nearest zero pixel, then find peaks in this
# distance map
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(maskb)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=9,
    labels=maskOpenb)

# perform a connected component analysis on the local peaks,
# using 8-connectivity, then appy the Watershed algorithm
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=maskOpenb)
print("[INFO] {} unique segments found".format(len(np.unique(labels)) - 1))

# loop over the unique labels returned by the Watershed
# algorithm
for label in np.unique(labels):
    # if the label is zero, we are examining the 'background'
    # so simply ignore it
    if label == 0:
        continue

    # otherwise, allocate memory for the label region and draw
    # it on the mask
    mask = np.zeros(maskOpenb.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255

    # detect contours in the mask and grab the largest one
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # draw a circle enclosing the object
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    #cv2.putText(img, "#{}".format(label), (int(x) - 10, int(y)),
            #   cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# show picture
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks in advance,
Jannik

EDIT: I tried to do a distance transformation for the blue beads which leads to the following results:
[Distance Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blYsn.jpg)

The added Code:

```
# sure background area
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(maskb,kernelOpen,iterations=5)
cv2.imshow("surebg", sure_bg)

# Finding sure foreground area
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(maskb,cv2.DIST_L2,3)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.14*dist_transform.max(),255,0)

# Finding unknown region
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
cv2.imshow("surefg", sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)

cv2.imshow("unknown", unknown)
# Marker labelling
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
# Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1
markers = markers+1
# Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
markers[unknown==255] = 0
markers = cv2.watershed(img,markers)
img[markers == -1] = [0,0,255]
print(ret)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
```

The Marking of the beads works quite well even some regions are unprecise.If i understood correct the "ret" value gives me the count of objects marked. Anyone any idea to further reach a precise counting?